# .bat for renewing IP until it starts with certain numbers

Tags: batch-file

My ISP, unfortunately, has different routes for different IPs, so pings are drastically different as well. Can someone please help me to write a .bat which performs ipconfig /release && ipconfig /renew until IP starts with some value? (I noticed that IPs starting with 147.*.*.* have the lowest ping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a powershell script that will do the job:

```
[string]$ip = (Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://ifconfig.me/ip").Content
while(!$ip.StartsWith('147')){
ipconfig /release *con*
ipconfig /renew
$ip = (Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://ifconfig.me/ip").Content
}
```

please put the number that you want your ip to start with inside the loop condition, it will continue to release and renew until you get an ip that starts with that number.

Answer (score 0):

Well your ISP may or may not change your IP address for a while, even if it is dynamic. I can only suggest going into your router's setting and releasing your WAN IP address and renewing it or simply restarting the router.

Note : for your request ipconfig /release / renew doesn't affect your external/ ISP IP address it renews the internal IP Address.

to release and renew you're internal ip address you can run the bellow commands in powershell:

```
ipconfig /release *Con*
ipconfig /renew
```

to get your external ip address you can use powershell to invoke a web request:

```
[string]$ip = (Invoke-WebRequest -uri "http://ifconfig.me/ip").Content
```

and then you can check if that ip starts with a specific number:

```
if($ip.StartsWith('147')){
#some code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am very new to batch files, where is the loop part that repeats the renewal if IP does not start, say, with 147?
I have configured my router so that my PC connects to it in Bridge mode, so I get external IPv4 directly. By the way, my ISP renews the IP address every time I invoke the commands

Comment: here is the script : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61286731/11130618